# Why is the outcome of a manual test executed via MS test runner being put in 'In Progress' state?

Tags: test-runner, manual-testing, azure-devops-server, tfs-2018

I am using TFS 2018 to run manual test cases (on chrome browser).  When I run a manual test, the Microsoft Test runner opens in a popup window. I mark the result of each test step, mark the test case result, and then save and close it.  The Microsoft Test runner window closes, however, the Outcome value displayed for the test I ran is set to In progress on the TFS web page.  Why is that?

test outcome after save and close

[image]

When I go to the run summary, it also shows outcome of in progress and the running time will continue to advance indefinitely. if I click on the test results tab within the run, it is showing the outcomes selected in the test runner for the test and its steps.  There doesn't appear to be a way to update the outcome of the run either.

run summary ss

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with Chrome.  Had to change the #allow-sync-xhr-in-page-dismissal setting from default to enabled.